# Using MSDTC in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, msdtc

I used Hyper-v to install one windows 2008 server machine, and copy the image to create another one and change the computer name, both of them are in the same domain, and I use a domain user as administrator to configure them.

After installing SQL server 2008, I tried T-SQL below:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO

BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION
EXEC CatalogSQLServer.Catalog.dbo.Hello
ROLLBACK
```

The first time I tried，I got the error information like:

> OLE DB provider 'SQLNCLI' for linked server '' returned message 'No transaction is active

I am 100% sure that I have configure DTC,Linked server and allow all inbound and outbound rule of firewall.  I configured [MSDTC based on these instructions](http://www.sqlvillage.com/Articles/Distributed%20Transaction%20Issue%20for%20Linked%20Server%20in%20SQL%20Server%202008.asp).

after that, I tried use command:

```
msdtc -uninstall 
msdtc -install
```

...and then restart dtc to re-install msdtc on CatalogSQLServer.  But this time, when I execute the test script, SSMS will keep executing for a very long time but didn't get any result.  Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: You have followed the directions for both instances?

Comment: When you do `msdtc -uninstall msdtc` you will loose all the settings you have made. You need to configure MSDTC **after** you installed it.

Comment: Can you check DNS, you need to ensure your forward and reverse lookup zones are correct for the two machines.

Answer (score 1):

First check that your computer name is not more than 15 characters as MSDTC relies on [NetBIOS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909264) , if it is less than that follow the instructions from Microsoft on [How to troubleshoot connectivity issues in MS DTC by using the DTCPing tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918331).